Layout was forced before the page was fully loaded
After making some CSS changes to the website, this message appeared in the FireFox console:

Layout was forced before the page was fully loaded. If stylesheets are not yet loaded this may cause a flash of unstyled content.

How to solve this? This problem sometimes causes fonts to not load properly.  I tried to resolve this message by gradually removing all the code. All the code used is simple css from bootstrap.
I tried various methods, such as:

adding an empty script tag at the end of the head or at the beginning of the body.
reverting the changes to the previous state did not fix the problem!
moving all script tags at the end
removing all other javascript and css codes!

I just added bootstarp.rtl.css v5.2.2:
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/content/2022/css/bootstrap.rtl.min.css" />

here is my html code:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fa" dir="rtl">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0 ,user-scalable=no" />
    <title>Sample Title</title>
    
    <meta http-equiv="content-language" content="fa" />

    <link rel="preload" as="font" href="/content/font/YekanXProVar/webfont/IRANYekanXVF.woff" type="font/woff" crossorigin="anonymous" />
    <link rel="preload" as="font" href="/content/font/YekanXProVar/webfont/staticfonts/IRANYekanX-regular.woff" type="font/woff" crossorigin="anonymous" />
    <link rel="preload" as="font" href="/content/font/YekanXProVar/webfont/staticfonts/IRANYekanX-bold.woff" type="font/woff" crossorigin="anonymous" />

    <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json" />
    <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#f5f5f5" />
    <meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="/content/load/Gabz144.png" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#f5f5f5" />

    <meta name="referrer" content="always" />
    <meta name="language" content="fa" />
    <meta name="document-type" content="Public" />
    <meta name="document-rating" content="General" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="resource-type" content="document" />

    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/content/load/Gbaz32.png" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/favicon.ico">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="author" content="sample author" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="sample Keywords " />
    <meta name="description" content="sample descr" />
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/content/2022/css/bootstrap.rtl.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/chegeni-index.min.css" />
 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/chegeni-common.min.js" defer></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/chegeni-index.min.js"  defer></script>

    <script>
        /*to prevent Firefox FOUC, this must be here*/
        let FF_FOUC_FIX;
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <script>0</script>
... every things here ...
</body>
</html>


How is your CSS inserted in the page? Through JavaScript, <style> or <link>? You left the most important thing out.

Thank you for your response. Question has been updated with  lines. The link to bootstrap.rtl.css v5.2.2 is causing the problem. I have not made any changes to the original bootstrap file.

You can remove all those closing slashes on all those HTML tags such as <meta> and <link>. No HTML specification has ever required or uses them and browsers ignore them because they have no meaning and do nothing.

Do you have any FF extensions loaded? Try starting FF in safe mode and see if the problem reproduces.

@Alohci Thank for response, No, it didn't solve the problem.

@Rob Thanks, I tested your solution. But removing the backslashes didn't solve the problem.

That wasn't a solution. It's pointing out HTML standards which doesn't tell anyone to put them there. Putting them there has no effect. They do nothing. And browsers ignore them. So don't put them there.

When you say "causes fonts to not load properly," do you mean that they don't load or that they load slowly so that there's a flash of wrong fonts initially? This question has some good discussion. I think I like putting <style>body {opacity: 0; visibility: hidden;}</style> (rather than display: none;) at the top of <head> and then <style>body {opacity: 1; visibility: visible;}</style> at the bottom of <body>. You're really just fighting for time for the styles/fonts to load.
